# How to filter a big .log file on Windows?

Tags: powershell, logging

I have a huge text-based log file, bigger than 1 GB. I'd like to filter it to create a new file with lines that contain only "error" messages.

I tried the following Powershell script:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'filename.log') -match 'error' | Set-Content -Path 'newFilename.log'
```

It works pretty good with a small files, but with this file it's just stuck...

Comment: You solutions look fine. For the final point: On Unix systems, `grep` is commonly used for that task, and it appears that the Powershell equivalent is `Select-String`. You might want to do some research in that direction.

Comment: Thanks Heinzi , it really work. It made it in 10 seconds.

Comment: You're welcome! To keep the questions and answers useful for future readers, we have a "one question per question" rule here on Stack Overflow. I have narrowed down your question to the part that you needed help with. Feel free to add the script you ended up using to the "answer box". Self-answering your own question is encouraged here, and it will help future readers with the same problem.

Comment: The parentheses load the whole thing into memory.  Piping to where-object might work bettter.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps even faster if you use [`switch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$errorData = switch -Wildcard -File 'X:\PathTo\filename.log' {
    '*error*' { $_ }  # output the line if keyword error is found
}
$errorData | Set-Content -Path 'X:\PathTo\newFilename.log'
```

Instead of using `-Wildcard`, you could also use `-Regex`. In that case, output the line on this condition: `'error' { $_ }`

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74096919/15339544), here is another memory friendly and fast alternative using the [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0) and [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0) .NET APIs to read and write *line-by-line*:

```
try {
    $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader] 'path\to\filename.log'
    $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] 'path\to\newFilename.log'

    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if($line -match 'Error') {
            $writer.WriteLine($line)
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $reader, $writer | ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```